# Python copy result the same as deepcopy

Tags: python, copy

This is the code that I have tried:

```
class van:
    pass
car5 = van()
car5.wheels = 4
print(car5.wheels) #4
car7 = copy.copy(car5)
car5.wheels = 6
print(car5.wheels) #6
print(car7.wheels) #4  the answer should be 6?
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to be different?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: expected the final print to be 6

Comment: There's `deepcopy` in the title but not in the question?!

Comment: *why* do you expect the final print to be `6`? This is the semantics of a copy. A deepcopy and a shallow copy should not behave any differently here.

Comment: You are coppying  values not references here so it will be `4` becouse at a time you were copying that value it was 4. Next you are overiding that field `wheels` in `car5` to 6 but `car7` will still have the same old value

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets break this down:

You start by creating `car5` and assinging it `4` wheels

You then copy all that data over to `car7` (so `car7` has 4 wheels)

At this point the cars are as follows:

```
car5.wheels = 4
car7.wheels = 4
```

You then change `car5`'s number of wheels to 6

```
car5.wheels = 6
car7.wheels = 4
```

**You haven't changed the number of wheels car7 has, it still has 4 wheels**